# Help with validation rules

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how to validate a section of a form using php.  If at least one of value 1-5 is checked, then at least one of value A-E must be checked.  Value's A-E cannot be allowed without at least one of 1-5 being checked.  Multiple values in each section can be selected, as long as there is at least one value in each section checked.

I have tried individual IF statements and arrays without success.

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples?  I am missing something and I am certain it is pretty obvious, right in my face.

```
 <div class="grid_12 alpha">
<strong>DISMISSAL</strong> - This section is to be used for errors which require dismissal by a Judge.
</div>

<div class="grid_5 alpha">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_a" />A
&nbsp;
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_b" />B
&nbsp;
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_c" />C
&nbsp;
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_d" />D
&nbsp;
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_e" />E
</div>

<div class="grid_3">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_mon" />Missing Officers Name
</div>

<div class="grid_4 omega">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_civ_crim_error" />Criminal/Civil Designation in Error
</div>

<div class="grid_12 alpha">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_improp_code_descr" />Improper Statute Number AND Description
</div>

<div class="grid_12 alpha">
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="dis_checkbox_other" />Other
<input id="input" type="text" name="dis_cit_other" size="115" maxlength="110" onkeypress="checkCapsLock( event )" />
</div>

<div class="grid_6 alpha">
Citing Officer:
<input id="input" type="text" name="dis_cit_officer" size="5" maxlength="5" onkeypress="checkCapsLock( event )" />
(Enter PR# only)
</div>

<div class="grid_6 omega">
Supervisor Notified:
<input id="input" type="text" name="dis_supvsr_notified" size="5" maxlength="5" onkeypress="checkCapsLock( event )" />
(Enter PR# only)
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show some code of the form?

Comment: Are you bound to use these names for the input controls or can you change them?

Comment: Okay, I know that I am a novice php'er, but I know for a fact the "names for the input controls" have absolutely no relevance to my question or the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

```
$number_boxes = array($_POST['box1'], $_POST['box2'], $_POST['box3'], $_POST['box4'], $_POST['box5']);

$letter_boxes = array($_POST['box_a'], $_POST['box_b'], $_POST['box_c'], $_POST['box_d'], $_POST['box_e']);

function validateCheckboxes($number_boxes, $letter_boxes){

    $numbers_checked = FALSE;
    $letters_checked = FALSE;

    foreach($number_boxes as $val){
        if($val) $numbers_checked = TRUE;
    }

    foreach($letter_boxes as $val){
        if($val) $letters_checked = TRUE;
    }

    if ($numbers_checked && !$letters_checked){
        return FALSE;
    } else if(!$numbers_checked && $letters_checked){
        return FALSE;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```